# Electric field created by a battery

Tags: electric-fields, capacitance, batteries

If I create an electric field using a battery between two parallel plates and leave the battery connected, will the electric field always exist for as long as the battery lasts, including normal self discharge?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Are you thinking about parallel plate capacitor?

Answer (score 1):

The potential difference across the parallel plates which determines the electric field between the plates of the capacitor will equal the potential difference across the terminals of the battery which if no current is flowing will equal the emf of the battery.

As the battery discharges its emf will drop and the capacitor will discharge through the battery thus lowering the electric field between the plates of the capacitor.

Comment: How would the battery discharge in this case ?

Comment: It is the self-discharge of the battery mainly due to the internal chemical reactions, which in case of lead-acid batteries happens at the rate of ~5%/mo.